# Is there a WPF equivalent for ToolStripButton?

Tags: wpf, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I'm learning WPF and have been trying to create a toolstrip. Is there a direct equivalent of the WinForms ToolStripButton or is the correct way of use just to add a normal button and format it?

I've found that Microsoft have a page that lists WinForm controls and their WPF equivalents [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx) but that doesn't mention the toolstripbutton.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/toolbar-overview

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just put buttons inside a [`ToolBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752063.aspx) and it will change the style of the buttons to make them look like a toolbar.

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button>Save</Button>
    <Button>Open</Button>
</ToolBar>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

If you want images in the buttons, you have to do the normal thing of modifying the content of the button.

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="..." />
</Button>
```

Comment: Cheers Ray, I suspected that, I just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something obvious. Winforms to WPF is quite a paradigm shift after all these years!

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush yeah it's quite a learning curve. I definitely like it though.

Comment: The more I use it the more it makes sense, I just wish I could visually design the dialogs as quickly as I could in Winforms.